# Executing a function at several timestamps

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to implement (in C++11/14) a way to execute a function at several timestamps. The scenario is as follows:

There is one main thread which could receive requests at any time. Requests could be in one of the formats: `remove object X at time Y` or `insert object X at time Y`, where X is an id I used to identify an object in our storage, and Y is a Unix timestamp. Time resolution will be second.

An intuitive way would be creating a new thread whenever a new request comes. This new thread then sleeps for some time specified in the request and removes/adds an object when it wakes up.

Another way would be polling. The main thread could store received requests. Then a separate thread could check all received requests every second and see if any removal/insertion need to be done.

It seems that both approaches I mentioned could incur a huge overhead, so I am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: How do you know there is a huge overhead ? Can you share some code here ?

Comment: What is the time resolution you are working with?  Seconds, Milliseconds, or Microseconds (or other)?

Comment: Have a delta list with 'time to execution of first item in list'.  The alarm handling code handles wakeups and executes the appropriate action.  When a new event arrives, if it should occur after the next event should occur, simply insert it into the delta list at the right point.  When the new event should occur before the current first item in the list, insert it into the list and wake the execution thread to let it know that there's a new 'first in list' item to be executed.

Comment: A delta list means that if the first item is due to be executed in 10 seconds, the next in 15 seconds, and the third in 18 seconds, your delta list will record 'in 10 seconds', 'after another 5 seconds', and 'after another 3 seconds' . You'll record enough time information that the process can resynchronize on an early wakeup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is implement a simple task-scheduler.

The simplest and most efficient way to do it requires only a single thread, a what-is-the-current-time call (e.g. [std::chrono::system_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)), and the math to add and subtract timestamps:

1. You'll need a data structure that will act as your schedule.  Your program will use this data structure to keep track of which operations need to be done when.  The data-items it will hold should each contain a timestamp, plus whatever information/parameters are required to perform the operation that is to be done at that time.  Most any data-structure can be used for this task, but [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is usually the most efficient one to choose.
2. For each operation that you want to have performed at a particular time, insert a record for that operation into your data-structure (along with the timestamp you want it to execution the operation at -- e.g. if you want it done 10 seconds from now, add 10 seconds to the current-system-time and use that as the record's timestamp).
3. Find the smallest timestamp in your schedule, and subtract the current-system-time from it.  If there are no events on the schedule at all, choose an arbitrary but very long time, e.g. 1 hour or 1 week or etc; or if your calculated-value is negative, use 0 instead.
4. Sleep for the amount of time you calculated in step 3.
5. Once you've woken up from your sleep, check the timestamp of the earliest event in your schedule.  If it's less than or equal to the current-system-timetime, execute that event, remove the event from the schedule, then goto (5).  Otherwise, goto (2).

That should get you the behavior you want with good accuracy and minimal overhead.  The only wrinkle is that if another thread wants to schedule another task while your scheduler thread is running, it will need to wake your scheduler-thread from its sleep, so that the scheduler-thread can immediately loop again through steps 2-5 (just in case the newly-inserted event needs to happen *before* the event it was previously planning to execute).  That can be implemented e.g. by using a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and [wait_for()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) or [wait_until()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) as your sleep mechanism, and having the other thread signal the condition variable if it needs you to wake early.  (Also the standard multithreading caveats apply, so be sure to serialize access to your schedule data-structure with a mutex or critical-section)

The benefit of doing it this way is that your thread almost never wakes up except when there is something for it to do; for example, if you only get one or two requests an hour, then your thread will only wake up one or two times an hour.  Also, the accuracy of the timing can be as fine-grained or as coarse-grained as you want; e.g. if you want 1-second granularity you can use timestamps calculated in seconds, or if you want finer accuracy you can use microseconds or nanoseconds or etc; the logic is the same either way.